# Google analytics analytics.js 2 two trackers colliding?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tracking, analytics.js

I am using the analytics.js script to track 3 sites - two 2nd level domains and one is a subdomain... for example: dom1.com, sub.dom1.com, dom2.com

The script and site I have trouble with is the dom1.com in this example. I have 2 properties which should aggregate the following data:

Property A : dom1.com + sub.dom1.com
Property B : dom1.com + sub.dom1.com + dom2.com

I have been looking for a bug in my code but can't figure out the problem, which is:

In Property A everything is aggregated correctly and both the domain and subdomain are sending their data fine. In Property B sub.dom1.com and dom2.com do send their data but dom1.com does not.

This is the script in the header of dom1.com:

```
ga('create', 'PropertyA', 'auto', {'name': 'trackerA'}, {'allowLinker': true});
ga('trackerA.send', 'pageview');
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['sub.dom1.com', 'dom1.com']);

ga('create', 'PropertyB', 'auto', {'name': 'trackerB'}, {'allowLinker': true});
ga('trackerB.send', 'pageview');
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['sub.dom1.com', 'dom1.com', 'dom2.com']);
```

I have tried moving the second tracker above in case the script is not run, but it didn't solve anything. I figure the problem is somewhere in the way I try to use the linker 2 times, but maybe do it wrong?

Thank you for any help, hope it helps someone else too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with your implementation (not all of these are contributing to your problem, but they are still generally best-practices):

1. In general, you should always require all plugins and invoke plugin initialization before doing anything else with a tracker since many plugins alter the behavior and/or data stored on the tracker(s).
2. You do not need to specify subdomains in the `autoLink` method, they get tracked automatically since you're using `auto` to enable automatic cookie domain configuration.
3. You cannot pass two objects to the `create` method, instead you should combine those options into a single object or use the shorthand (e.g. `ga('create', trackingID, cookieDomain, trackerName, additionalConfigOptions);`
4. When using multiple trackers, you must specify the tracker name when requiring plugins and invoking plugins methods (e.g. `ga('trackerName.require', 'pluginName');` and `ga('trackerName.pluginName:methodName', methodOptions);`)

If you update your code as follows, it should work:

```
ga('create', 'PropertyA', 'auto', 'trackerA', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('trackerA.require', 'linker');
ga('trackerA.linker:autoLink', ['dom1.com']);
ga('trackerA.send', 'pageview');

ga('create', 'PropertyB', 'auto', 'trackerB', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('trackerB.require', 'linker');
ga('trackerB.linker:autoLink', ['dom1.com', 'dom2.com']);
ga('trackerB.send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Thanks I set it up following your answer. But it still doesn't work. :/

Comment: Is it possible that the 'auto' cookie domains have a conflict?

Comment: What doesn't work? When you go from domain1 to domain2 do you see the `_ga=XXXXXXX` parameter in the URL? Are you using the [debug version of analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#debug) to see if there are any errors logged to the console?

Comment: To answer your second question, no, using `'auto'` for the `cookieDomain` will have no affect on two different domains.

Comment: Sorry the mistake was on my end. The code works. Thank You! I didn't know about the debugger, it helped a lot. I will mark your answer as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include the tracker names when you call the "require" and "linker" methods:

```
ga('trackerA.require', 'linker');
ga('trackerA.linker:autoLink', ['sub.dom1.com', 'dom1.com']);
```

Same with Property B.